# Задание разноцветного текста QLabel в Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

Я хочу каждому слову текста `QLabel` задать свой цвет.

Я видел решение данной задачи в интерпретаторе :

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
 
app = Qt.QApplication([])
 
label = Qt.QLabel()

txt = '''<font color="red">Это</font><br>
<font color="green">Цветной</font><br>
<font color="blue">Текст</font><br>'''

label.setText(txt)
label.setFont(Qt.QFont("sefif",32))

label.resize(400,300)
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

Но как мне сделать это не посредственно в самом *Qt Designer*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Выбираем виджет `QLabel`.
2. Вставляем текст:

   `<`font color="red"`>`Это`<`/font`><`br`>`
   `<`font color="green"`>`Цветной`<`/font`><`br`>`
   `<`font color="blue"`>`Текст`<`/font`><`br`>`

и устанавливаем нужный `textFormat`

3. Центрируем текст, если надо.
4. Выбирает нужный менеджер компоновки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @assert, зачем вы удалили вопрос  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369532 ? Если вы нашли решение вопроса - опубликуйте его в ответ. Я уже потратил некоторое время для подготовки ответа для вас, а вы удаляете вопрос. Я не рекомендую вам удалять вопросы и предлагаю восстановить вопрос.