# Привязка размера объектов к размеру окна

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать привязку размера объектов к размеру окну в `Qt Designer` с таким же соотношением размеров, я пытался сделать через `Layouts`, но я не мог наслаивать один объект на другой.

Также в самом коде я попытался запрашивать текущий размер окна и масштабировать объекты в зависимости на сколько изменился размер экрана от изначального, но в  метод `.setGeometry()` нельзя было заносить вещественные числа, а при округлении объекты смешались.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import os


class Ui_Enrollee(object):
    def setupUi(self, Enrollee):
        Enrollee.setObjectName('Enrollee')
        Enrollee.resize(450, 800)
        Enrollee.setWindowTitle(' ')
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd() + '\\other\\design\\icon.png'))
        Enrollee.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Enrollee.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ffffff')
        self.WidgetsEnrollee = QtWidgets.QWidget(Enrollee)
        self.WidgetsEnrollee.setObjectName('WidgetsEnrollee')
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 95, 20, 690))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setStyleSheet('QScrollBar:vertical {\n'
'    border-radius: 10;\n'
'    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
'    background: #595959;\n'
'}\n'
'QScrollBar::handle:vertical {\n'
'    border-radius: 8;\n'
'    background: #ffffff;\n'
'    min-width: 20px;\n'
'}\n'
'QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n'
'    border: none;\n'
'    background: none;\n'
'}\n'
'QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical{\n'
'    background: none;\n'
'}')
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName('verticalScrollBar')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 20, 360, 45))
        self.label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #595959;\n'
'border-radius: 22;\n'
'color: #ffffff;')
        self.label.setText('')
        self.label.setObjectName('label')
        self.ninth_grade = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.ninth_grade.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 20, 180, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ninth_grade.setFont(font)
        self.ninth_grade.setStyleSheet('background-color: #363636;\n'
'border-radius: 22;\n'
'color: #ffffff;\n'
'')
        self.ninth_grade.setObjectName('ninth_grade')
        self.eleventh_grade = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.eleventh_grade.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 20, 180, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.eleventh_grade.setFont(font)
        self.eleventh_grade.setStyleSheet('background-color: #595959;\n'
'border-radius: 22;\n'
'color: #ffffff;')
        self.eleventh_grade.setObjectName('eleventh_grade')
        n = 1
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        if 125 + 28 * (n - 1) > 745:
            self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 95, 400, 125 + 28 * (n - 1) - 35))
        else:
            self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 95, 400, 690))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.frame.setFont(font)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 10;\n'
'border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
'color: #000000;')
        self.frame.setText('')
        self.frame.setIndent(10)
        self.frame.setObjectName('frame')
        self.math = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.math.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(265, 85, 70, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.math.setFont(font)
        self.math.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 10;\n'
'border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
'color: #000000;')
        self.math.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.math.setIndent(0)
        self.math.setObjectName('math')
        self.ukrain = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.ukrain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 85, 70, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ukrain.setFont(font)
        self.ukrain.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 10;\n'
'border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
'color: #000000;')
        self.ukrain.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ukrain.setIndent(0)
        self.ukrain.setObjectName('ukrain')
        
        for i in range(n):
            self.name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
            self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(43, 125 + 28 * i, 222, 30))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily('Montserrat')
            font.setPointSize(9)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.name.setFont(font)
            self.name.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
    'color: #000000;')
            self.name.setText('')
            self.name.setIndent(10)
            self.name.setObjectName('name')
            self.grade_math = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
            self.grade_math.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(263, 125 + 28 * i, 77, 30))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily('Montserrat')
            font.setPointSize(9)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.grade_math.setFont(font)
            self.grade_math.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
    'color: #000000;')
            self.grade_math.setText('')
            self.grade_math.setIndent(10)
            self.grade_math.setObjectName('grade_math')
            self.grade_ukrain = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
            self.grade_ukrain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(338, 125 + 28 * i, 77, 30))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily('Montserrat')
            font.setPointSize(9)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.grade_ukrain.setFont(font)
            self.grade_ukrain.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
    'color: #000000;')
            self.grade_ukrain.setText('')
            self.grade_ukrain.setIndent(10)
            self.grade_ukrain.setObjectName('grade_ukrain')
            self.num = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
            self.num.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 125 + 28 * i, 30, 30))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily('Montserrat')
            font.setPointSize(9)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.num.setFont(font)
            self.num.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
    'color: #000000;')
            self.num.setText('')
            self.num.setIndent(10)
            self.num.setObjectName('num')
        Enrollee.setCentralWidget(self.WidgetsEnrollee)

        self.retranslateUi(Enrollee)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Enrollee)

    def retranslateUi(self, Enrollee):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.ninth_grade.setText(_translate('Enrollee', 'button 1'))
        self.eleventh_grade.setText(_translate('Enrollee', 'button 2'))
        self.math.setText(_translate('Enrollee', 'TEXT 1'))
        self.ukrain.setText(_translate('Enrollee', 'TEXT 2'))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Enrollee):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.bnts = QButtonGroup()
        self.bnts.setExclusive(True)
        self.bnts.addButton(self.eleventh_grade)
        self.bnts.addButton(self.ninth_grade)
        self.bnts.buttonClicked.connect(self.color_change)
        self.color_change(self.ninth_grade)

    def color_change(self, but):
        but.setStyleSheet('background-color: #363636;\nborder-radius: 22;\ncolor: #ffffff;\n')
        if but == self.eleventh_grade:
            self.ninth_grade.setStyleSheet('background-color: #595959;\nborder-radius: 22;\ncolor: #ffffff;\n')
        else:
            self.eleventh_grade.setStyleSheet('background-color: #595959;\nborder-radius: 22;\ncolor: #ffffff;\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

UI модель приложения можно посмотреть здесь :[ui модель](https://gitlab.com/strtz57/file-educ5.py/-/blob/797b67f40b185406b6a0feb53a5d11082dda33d2/educ5.ui)

Comment: qwerty, пожалуйста опубликуйте ваш модуль `.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick я уже отредактировал вопрос и добавил модель UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю что за прямоугольники вы рисуете в цикле и для чего они. Я вставил вместо них `QTableWidget`.

Выполните:

```
pyuic5 q1369532.ui -o q1369532_ui.py -x
```

и запустите **main.py**

---

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

---

**q1369532.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>450</width>
    <height>650</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>200</width>
           <height>44</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>16777215</width>
           <height>44</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">
background-color: #595959;
border-radius: 22;
color: #ffffff;


margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;

padding-left: -20px;
padding-right: -20px;



</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeConstraint">
             <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="ninth_grade">
              <property name="maximumSize">
               <size>
                <width>16777215</width>
                <height>42</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="styleSheet">
               <string notr="true">background-color: #363636;
border-radius: 21px;
color: #ffffff;</string>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Button 1</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="eleventh_grade">
              <property name="minimumSize">
               <size>
                <width>0</width>
                <height>0</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="maximumSize">
               <size>
                <width>16777215</width>
                <height>42</height>
               </size>
              </property>
              <property name="styleSheet">
               <string notr="true">background-color: #595959;
border-radius: 21px;
color: #ffffff;

</string>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>Button 2</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_3">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>20</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #f0f;
border-radius: 10;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="frameShape">
             <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="frameShadow">
             <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_5">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>21</width>
              <height>16777215</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="frameShape">
             <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="frameShadow">
             <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
             <property name="spacing">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="leftMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="topMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="rightMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="bottomMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <item>
              <widget class="QScrollBar" name="verticalScrollBar">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>20</width>
                 <height>220</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">QScrollBar:vertical {
    border-radius: 10;
    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
    background: #595959;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    border-radius: 8;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical{
    background: none;
}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="orientation">
                <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from q1369532_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)   
        self.widget.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.h_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.h_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.math = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.math.setText('TEXT 1')
        self.math.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.math.setFont(font)
        self.math.setStyleSheet('background-color: #fff; border-radius: 10;\n'
'border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
'color: #000000;')
        self.math.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.math.setIndent(0)
        self.math.setObjectName('math')
        
        self.ukrain = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.ukrain.setText('TEXT 2')
        self.ukrain.setFixedSize(70, 30)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Montserrat')
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ukrain.setFont(font)
        self.ukrain.setStyleSheet('background-color: #fff; border-radius: 10;\n'
'border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n'
'color: #000000;')
        self.ukrain.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ukrain.setIndent(0)
        self.ukrain.setObjectName('ukrain')        
        
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.math)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.ukrain)

        self.eleventh_grade.clicked.connect(self.color_change)
        self.ninth_grade.clicked.connect(self.color_change)
        self.ninth_grade.click()
        
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: #fff; 
            border-radius: 10px; 
            border: 2px solid #f0f;
        ''')

        self.h_layout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.h_layout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 4)        
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(5, 4)
        self.col_headers = ['A', 'Hello', 'World', 'D',]
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.col_headers)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet('border: 1px; border-radius: 10px;')
        self.h_layout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        
    def color_change(self):
        but = self.sender()
        but.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: #363636; 
            color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 21px;
        ''')
        if but == self.eleventh_grade:
            self.ninth_grade.setStyleSheet('''
                background-color: #595959; 
                color: #ffffff;
                border-radius: 21px;
            ''') 
        else:
            self.eleventh_grade.setStyleSheet('''
                background-color: #595959; 
                color: #ffffff;
                border-radius: 21px;
            ''')        
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.widget.move(self.size().width() - 215, 67)
        

Stylesheet = """
QHeaderView {
    background:transparent; 
    color: #00f;
    font: 75 14pt 'MS Shell Dlg 2';
} 
QHeaderView::section {border: 0;}
"""        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)            
    
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]